# PL/SQL Developer, Oracle. I can connect to the schema but can't see any tables and have no access to them

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a login and password to the oracle schema and can connect to it. But I can't see any tables, procedures, nothing. Every folder in objects list is empty.

I tried to change between ,  and  (those are only options I have in Objects workplace) but it didin't help.
I tried to connect as SYSDBA, didin't help either
I tried `select * from ALL_TABLES` with some variations, every command returns nothing (even not "no row selected", just an empty square, like an empty cell)

It took plenty of time to connect to scheme and configure Oracle on my computer, but I think something might be wrong with it. I am new to Oracle and I am doing pretty bad, so any help will be higly appreciated

screenshot to understand the problem better:[image]

UPDATE: I made it work following this steps:

1. Install Oracle Instant Client 11 (note: oracle site requires registration). I went just with Basic version
2. Exctract files in C:\oracle on my computer
3. Manually made folder network\admin in my C:\oracle\instant_client folder
4. Put tnsnames.ora & sqlnet.ora in that folder
5. Added some variables to my environment variables

```
ORACLE_HOME=C:\instant_client
SQL_PATH=C:\instant_client
TNS_ADMIN=C:\instant_client\network\admin
Path= C:\instant_client
```

6. Manually wrote the path to oci.dll in OCI Library window in Preferences
7. Restart PL/SQL

Hapilly, it worked for me and maybe it can help someone else as well.
Thanks everyone for the help proveided, I really appreciate it

Comment: Try to connect to Oracle with sqlplus, and check the result of the "select owner, table_name from dba_tables;" statement.

Comment: Well, the fact that there's some user you managed to connect to doesn't mean it contains **any objects** (tables, views, whatever). By default, when user is created, it is "empty". As it is your database, you can connect as e.g. SYS (as SYSDBA). It should have plenty of objects. I'm not sure what "SYSDBA" you mentioned it is, though.

Comment: I can't connect through sql_plus: ```ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error```

Comment: @Littlefoot that's not the database I created. I was given it on the project and my teammates can see the tables clearly. They connect with teh same login-password.

Comment: Try to run the tnsping utility, for example: tnsping orcl or something like that. Does it work? Perhaps you have some problem with your Oracle client installation or its settings.

Comment: @Kapitany `dba_tables` is not accessible by default, there should be `all_tables`: *They can be queried only by users with the SYSDBA system privilege or SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege, or SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role, or by users with direct privileges granted to them* ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/about-static-data-dictionary-views.html))

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the cause of the problem of paut is somewhere else. He cannot connect to Oracle with sqlplus.

Comment: @Kapitany I found tnsspring in my bin folder of my client but it just open and close some kind of console

Comment: After pressing Windows + R run cmd.exe, so you can use the Windows command line. Here you can run tnsping orcl or something like that. Please show us the output of tnsping.

Comment: I have an error ```MSVCP120.dll is not found``` when i run tnsping orcl in cmd

Comment: You should your Windows path environment variable. Try to add to the path of the Oracle client's bin folder.

Comment: @Kapitany it's in PATH, I added it